# Issues pushing an object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Cant seem to push an object into my array. Just not understanding what I'm missing here.

In my console log I see this:

```
push: {
    "s": {
        "r": 12,
        "c": 2
    },
    "e": {
        "r": 12,
        "c": 7
    }
}
```

Repeated by I am expecting the `r` values to increase on each loops but just keeps outputting the same value no matter what I do. This is an example of my code:

```
var ExportExcel = function(){

    var MergeMe = [];
    console.log(MergeMe);
        
    var gap_counter = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.Array_of_Cases, function(case) {
        gap_counter++;
        var temp_object = { s: { r: (8+gap_counter), c: 2 }, e: { r: (8+gap_counter), c: 7 } };
        MergeMe.push = (temp_object);
        console.log(MergeMe);
    }

}
```

Anyone see any issues with this?

Repeated by I am expecting the `r` values to increase on each loops but just keeps outputting the same value no matter what I do.

Comment: `MergeMe.push = (temp_object);` - what is that supposed to be?

Comment: Can the `case` code be used for variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just didn't call the push function correctly. Your code to push the object into your array is `MergeMe.push = (temp_object);`, but it should just be `MergeMe.push(temp_object);`.

Comment: OMG, been stuck on this for days lol Good catch completly overlooked this typo. Thx!